# How can I change the label color on a google chart API bar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I had an image that perfectly shows what my issue is but I don't have enough points to post it.

Basically, I have a bar chart using Google's API and I want to color the labels BLACK whenever they're outside the bar.  Currently they are the same color as the bar and that is difficult to read.
Several things are variables because I have multiple charts and I want them to look consistent in terms of fonts, weights, etc.,

```
 options = {
    chartArea: { width: '70%' },
    tooltip: { textStyle: { fontSize: intFontSizeAnnotation } },
    title: '',
    vAxis: { title: '', textStyle: { fontName: default_font, fontSize: intFontSizeAxis }, titleTextStyle: { fontName: default_font, fontSize: intFontSizeTitle }, gridlines: { color: 'transparent' }, label: { color: '#000000' } },
    hAxis: {
        textStyle: { fontName: default_font, fontSize: intFontSizeAxis }, titleTextStyle: { fontName: default_font, fontSize: intFontSizeTitle },
        minValue: min_overall_mpg_initMPGMake, maxValue: max_overall_mpg_initMPGMake, format: '0.00', title: 'Overall MPG', label: {color: '#000000'}
    },
    legend: 'none',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    annotations: { textStyle: { fontName: default_font, fontSize: intFontSizeAnnotation, color: '#000000' } },
    tooltip: { textStyle: { fontName: default_font, fontSize: intFontSizeTitle } }
};

mpg_make_data.unshift(['Type', 'MPG', { type: 'string', role: 'annotation' }, { role: 'style' }]);

drawChart('mpg-make', 'bar', mpg_make_data, options, 'mpg');
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm interested because I'm trying to accomplish the same thing and it's impossible to find documentation on how this is done.

Comment: Nope, switched to DevExpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this
titleTextStyle: {
    color: '#a34f8b'
}